# Delete an item in a list of attribute values in a DynamoDB Table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I need to delete one item from a list in a dynamodb table, but I am getting below error. Could someone help me to resolve it

```
aws dynamodb delete-item \
--table-name  dev-table \
--key '{"Environment":{"S":"all"}}' \
--expression-attribute-names '{"#v": "Values"}' \
--expression-attribute-values '{":vals": {"L": [ { "S": "test"}]}}'
```

**Error:**

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the DeleteItem operation: ExpressionAttributeNames can only be specified when using expressions
```

Answer (score 2):

Could not yet figure out how to do it with cli, but here is a lambda that would do this:

```
import boto3

REGION = 'us-east-1'
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', REGION) 
env_table = dynamodb.Table('dev-table') 

def get_index(totallist):
    for item in totallist:
        if item['Environment'] == 'all':
            index = item['Values'].index('test')
    return index

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    totallist = env_table.scan()['Items']
    index = get_index(totallist)
    response = env_table.update_item(
            Key={'Environment': 'all'},
            UpdateExpression=f"REMOVE #v[{index}]",
            ExpressionAttributeNames={'#v': 'Values'},
        )
    return
```

Make sure you add an IAM role to the lambda function to allow access to dynamodb.

Comment: I need to delete only one item which is ```test``` in this ```Values``` list. if we don't need last 2 lines, how do we mention which item to delete?

Comment: Please see the updated response.  It assumes that 'Values' is the table's primary key

Comment: ... or you are trying to delete any number of records with primary key 'Environment' = 'all' and 'Values' attribute with the value 'test'?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to delete one record in 'Values' attribute with the value 'test' with primary key 'Environment' = 'all'

Comment: @AlfredHitchkock, please see the python code above.  Will still try to find a cli solution in a couple of days.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you need is `updateItem`. In DynamoDB an `item` is a record in the table. If you're trying to modify a list within your record, you need to use the [UpdateItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html) request.

Your request should look like below.

```
aws dynamodb update-item \
--table-name  dev-table \
--key '{"Environment":{"S":"all"}}' \
--update-expression "SET Values = :vals" \
--expression-attribute-values '{":vals": {"L": [ { "S": "test"}]}}'
--return-values ALL_NEW
```

Here's an example [request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.SET.ModifyingAttributes).

Comment: ```An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: Invalid UpdateExpression: Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: Values``` observed this error

Comment: You might want to rename your attribute name as `values` is a reserved one. It's advised to not use them: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ReservedWords.html

Comment: tried this code with new attribute, it is just replacing the entire attribute values and appending it. its not deleting the old one.